# Countable additivity and continuity of measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let N be the set of all natural numbers, $2^N$ the set of all subsets of N with product topology and $\mu:2^N \rightarrow G$ an additive set function. Prove that $\mu$ is countably additive iff it is continuous where $G$ denotes a commutative Hausdorff complete topological group.

Comment: What does it mean for $\mu$ to be continuous?

Comment: The topology on $\mathbb N$ is discrete. The powerset $2^{\mathbb N}$ is not a product space so this is not something where you will induce a product topology.

Comment: @s.harp The power set can be canonically identified with $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is a product space. The product topology is a rather natural topology on the power set.

Comment: Yes, my question in linked to the continuity part. Is it really saying that such functions are topologically continuous? Or does it have to do with how measures are usually viewed as continuous using the partial order of sets?

Comment: $2^{\mathbb N}$ is metrizable and a sequence $(A_n)$ of subsets of $\mathbb N$ converges in the product topology if and only $\liminf A_n=\limsup A_n$, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit

Comment: It's not difficult to show that continuity implies countable additivity. In the opposite direction, it is immediate that $\mu$ is compatible with monotone limits, but I don't see how to deal with the general case (that $G$ does not carry an order structure makes it harder, I think).

Comment: @MaoWao can you point me in the direction of a proof of the statement you make: a sequence (An) of subsets of N converges in the product topology if and only lim infAn=lim supAn

Comment: Write all sets as indicator functions. The product topology is the topology of pointwise convergence. Check that $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ in the sense of sets are obtained by taking $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the indicator functions pointwise. But pointwise, you just have a sequence in $\{0,1\}$ and the above statement is clear.